# Motorola G9 didn't support \n character in notification message

Tags: android

I'm testing notification in Motorola G9 and saw that it didn't support "\n" (down line) character in body of notification.
That mean "\n" still show on text and it didn't break text line.

I tested on Xiaomi, Samsung but "\n" still work.

It running on Android 10.

Anyone have exp about this issue. Please let me know.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The defult style for notification set text in single line mode. To support '\n', You need to set a style to your NotificationCompat.Builder object.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder...

String displayMessageText = "My \n Message";

mBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(displayMessageText));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I also set big text style to my notification config. Issue still occurs when app is in background mode (OS handle notification)

Comment: It seems <br> works for line breaks. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded